# primitive list's don't seem to match even when values/order are the same? Is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a list of ints[] that I list one at a time.  I found an intresting pattern that the results seem to reverse so to test it I reversed the list that came into my method and then displayed them, and found they matched.  I want to programmatically find them but when I print the list itself as a string the results don't match even if the items/order match.

Here's the method(it simply gets data in, reverses the order and prints both..nothing fancy):

```
private static void show (int [] arr) { 
    //before we print results lets reverse the list and study if there's something we can do to make this go faster
    int[] ReversedList = new int[arr.length];
    for (int x = arr.length-1, y=0; x>=0;x--, y++) {
        ReversedList[y] = arr[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        //System.out.print (" " + (arr [x] + low[x]));
        System.out.print (" " + (arr[x]));
    }
    System.out.println (" " + arr.toString());
    for (int x = 0; x < ReversedList.length; x++) {
        //System.out.print (" " + (arr [x] + low[x]));
        System.out.print (" " + (ReversedList[x]));
    }

    System.out.println (" " + ReversedList.toString() + "  ***");
   //System.out.println("*****************");
}
```

but the strings don't match.  Here's a snippet of the output( *** means it been reversed):

```
 0 0 0 20 [I@199a0c7c
 20 0 0 0 [I@50a9ae05  ***
....
 20 0 0 0 [I@1e9af0b1
 0 0 0 20 [I@4e300429  ***
```

They all are like this and I'm unsure why they don't match when they are the same(at least look the same).  I have a arraylist called `results` that has all the int[] and I tried to do a results.indexof(reversed) but no luck(I get '-1' for everything).  How can I find matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the addresses for the int arrays you have. The data is the same, but the data is stored in multiple locations because you are using multiple instances.

To compare arrays, use [`Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29). Alternatively, you can view the information in the arrays in a better format with [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Thanks I'm a bit(generally) confused about two things, when I try to lookup a `ArrayList<int[]> result2` using `result2.indexOf(Arrays.toString(ReversedList))` it still gives -1..if there's something else I need to convert it to then let me know otherwise I can create a method to do this.  But the other thing thats confusing is if unlike c, Java doesn't allow you to use malloc or free, why is it giving me the memory address?

Comment: @Lostsoul Can you post your entire code dealing with these arrays so we can see exactly where the problem arises?

Comment: The problem is that `indexOf` uses `Object.equals()` to check for equality, which is just reference equality for arrays.  If you want to use a `List<int[]>`, you don't really have a choice but to iterate over the list yourself rather than using a utility method like `indexOf`.

Comment: @Louis Thanks, that's what I suspected. I suppose if he wanted to, he could extend `ArrayList` to implement his own functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all object addresses.  They refer to different integer arrays, so they wouldn't match up.

Use the [`java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) method instead to visually see the contents of an array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
// ... code
System.out.println (" " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score -3):

What is getting printed is the HASHCODE. It is like both are separate objects and are stored separately on the heap memory. HashCode is nothing but unique number allocated to each object by the JVM. I hope this  is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not of the influence that a hashcode is the same as a memory address.

Comment: " If HASHCODE is confusing you just remember it as a memory address." -1

Comment: Dude i just asked him to remember it that way if it is confusing and i have clearly mentioned it there.

Comment: No, because the hashcode isn't being printed - it's the address of the instantiated object, instead.

Comment: Still invalid because of what Makoto said.  Anyway, telling someone something completely wrong because it's sort of convenient doesn't make it ok.  A hash and a memory location are two entirely disjoint concepts.